# What do we call entities (like $\sum$) that bind variables?

Tags: logic, terminology

In logic, we refer to entities like $\forall$ and $\exists$ as *quantifiers*, because they bind variables. However, variable-binding doesn't just occur at quantifiers. For example, the symbol $i$ denotes a bound variable in the following expression.

$$\sum_{i=0}^n i$$

What do we call entities (like $\sum$) that bind variables? I'd like to know the official name of such entities, so I can read up on how they're formalized in logical systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen them called 'binders' in the context of automated proof tools.

For the HOL family, there is [HOL Light](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/hol-light/), where section 6.1 Quantifiers in ["HOL Light Tutorial (for version 2.20)"](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/hol-light/tutorial_220.pdf) says

> Constants such as ‘!’ that are parsed and printed in this abbreviated form when
> applied to abstractions are called *binders*, because they appear to bind variables. (But
> strictly speaking they don’t: it’s the underlying abstraction that does that.)

Also documents related to HOL4 frequently uses the term 'binder'.

Mizar does not have binders, but there is an article ["A proposed syntax for binders in Mizar"](http://www.cs.ru.nl/F.Wiedijk/mizar/binder.pdf) by Freek Wiedijk.

In essence, a binder is a higher-order function: it is a function that maps a function from $\;X\;$ to $\;Y\;$ to a value of type $\;Z\;$, where very often $\;Y\;$ and $\;Z\;$ are the same.  So for instance $\;\forall \;:\; (U \to \text{boolean}) \to \text{boolean}\;$ and $\;\sum : (U \to \mathbb C) \to \mathbb C\;$.

(Personally, I don't like to use the term 'quantifier' for operators like $\;\prod\;$ and $\;\int\;$, as Gries-Schneider does.  But I really like Gries-Schneider's general theory of binders/quantifiers.)

Answer (score 7):

In "A Logical Approach to Discrete Math" by David Gries & Fred Schneider authors call them all quantifiers (actual quantifiers, summation, multiplication and others). There is a whole section in which they develop general theory for those structures.

Comment: See also the section Quantification in Edsger W. Dijkstra's [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html): Gries-Schneider based their presentation on the notations from Dijkstra/Feijen/Scholten.

Answer (score 4):

See Dirk van Dalen, *Logic and Structure* (5th ed - 2013), page 58 :

> > In mathematics there are a number of *variable-binding operations*, such as summation,
> >     integration, abstraction. Consider, for example, integration, in  $ \int \mathrm{\sin}x dx$ the variable plays an unusual role for a variable. [...] We say that the variable $x$ is *bound* by the integration symbol.

The symbol

> > $$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i$$

was introduced by Fourier in 1820. The sigma-notation is called "summation". The quantity $a_i$ after the "big" $\Sigma$ is called the summand.

The index variable $i$ is bound to the sigma-notation.

This feature is in common with the integral sign, both being "generalization" of the sum operation.

If you think at the universal quantifier as an "infinite conjunction" (i.e. $\forall x (x \ge 0)$ as : $(0 \ge 0) \land (1 \ge 0) \land (2 \ge 0) \land ...$) and the existential one as as infinite disjunction, you can see immediately the connection with summation ($\Sigma$) and "generalized" product ($\Pi$).

This analogy is much more clear if you think that in the [Algebra of logic tradition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/algebra-logic-tradition/) : Boole, Peirce and Schroeder, conjunction was symbolized as "$.$" and disjunction as "+".

Peirce in 1870 introduced the quantifier symbols - see [Peirce's Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/peirce-logic/) - and he  used for them exactly the simbols $\Pi$ and $\Sigma$, where :

> "$\Pi$ signifies logical multiplication and $\Sigma$ signifies logical addition".

In conclusion, the summation is a *variable-binding operator*, like a quantifier.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This is hard book by the way ;)