# Is it wrong to call all math operators, functionals and other things that take input and provide output just "functions"?

Tags: functions

I am more of a programmer than a mathematician, so in my mind a functions can take any type of input and can produce any kind of output. For example I see the derivative operator $\frac{d}{dx}$ as a function that takes a function as its argument and returns a function. Is this wrong in math?

Comment: A function is by definition a type of relation with the condition that each input has one output.

Comment: No it's not wrong, all those things are functions. We have different names for various sorts of functions to make things easier to follow - if I read something about an "operator" that tells me something different from if I read something about a functional".

Comment: You may find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692562/what-do-we-call-entities-like-sum-that-bind-variables) relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only 2 things you need to be certain about is that for each input there is only one possible output. You can't have "$f(x) = y$ such that $y^2 = x$" because both $\sqrt(x)$ and $-\sqrt(x)$ are acceptable output.

and that the output for a give input is consistent: $f(x) = $ a random number: is not a function.

and, I should mention, a function must be well defined.  No matter how the input is expressed, its method of processing is clear and consistent.  $f(a/b) = a + b$ is not a well defined function as $f(1/2) = 3 \ne f(2/4) = 6$ and $f(\pi) = ??????$.

But to say $d/dx$ is a function that maps $f$ to $f'$ is *absolutely* correct.  In fact we consider the set of all real functions to be a topological space and we *do* study functions that map functions to functions.  That isn't considered strange or weird or incorrect at all.

===

The technical definitions is $f:S \rightarrow T$ is a function that maps elements of a set S to elements of a set T if it is a collection of ordered pairs $F = ${$(a, b) | a \in S, b \in T$} so that the "a" terms are unique; that  is to say.  If (a, b) and (c, d) $\in F$ and $b \ne d$ then $a \ne c$.

There is *no* limitation whatsoever what the sets $S$ and $T$ are.  They can be anything including sets of functions, sets of sets, sets rules or processes, programming points, whatever.

Comment: You're saying that function's method of processing must be clear and consistent. What about the busy beaver function? It's uncomputable. I dont think its method of processing is clear.

Comment: I didn't say the processing itself was clear and consistent.   I'm saying it's definition and interpretation must be consistent.  The busy beaver function,  *is* clear and consistent.  the function on 5 will be different if we interpret 5 as 2 + 3.  What do you think is unclear about its method of processing?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly reasonable view to adopt, especially when one is only working with the derivative of functions $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$. For whatever reason, one more often sees the letter $D$ refer to the differentiation *operator* (which is basically another word for function), which is exactly the function you describe - it takes in a differentiable function and outputs the derivative. One can certainly express differentiation rules with this notation:
$$D(f+g)=Df+Dg$$
$$D(f\cdot g)=(Df)\cdot g + f\cdot (Dg)$$
$$D(f\circ g)=(Df)\circ g \cdot Dg$$
and really, most any elementary notion about differential calculus can be expressed perfectly well - which tells us that we won't run into trouble just by treating the derivative as an a function operating on functions. This idea actually asserts itself as being very important in certain branches of analysis, where treating $D$ as a linear map lets us use linear algebra to address the theory of differential equations. It's worth noting that it would not be incorrect to call this simply a "function" rather than an "operator", but the latter is a more specific term (referring to functions between modules or vector spaces).

In elementary contexts, one might avoid various errors by considering your notion - for instance, it forces us to distinguish equality of *functions* and equality of *values*, so we won't look at an equation like $x^2=1$ and differentiate both sides to get $2x=0$. This sort of ambiguity presents itself pretty frequently, since we're using letters like $x$ both to denote the argument of a function *and* to denote variables, but thinking of things like the derivative as operating on functions largely saves us from this.

It is worth noting that there *are* alternate ways of viewing the notation $\frac{d}{dx}$. For instance, one may use differential forms, where we treat $d$ itself as an operator to write statements like:
$$df(x)=f'(x)\,dx$$
which looks *a lot* like the notation
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f'(x).$$
This view tends to cover differential calculus just as well, but extend more neatly to integral calculus. For instance, they make it easy to express substitution rules - like, one can note that
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=1}dx=1$$
but substituting $2u=x$, we can differentiate to get $2du =dx$ in this notation and then actually substitute in for $dx$
$$\int_{x=0}^{x=1}2\,du=\int_{u=0}^{u=1/2}2\,du=1$$
whereas the analogous statement where we only have an integral operator acting on *functions* is harder to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is perfectly correct, and even mathematicians use this perspective sometimes: for example, in some contexts we will view $\frac{d}{dx}$ as being a function of type

$$\mathbb{R}[x] \leftarrow \mathbb{R}[x],$$

where $\mathbb{R}[x]$ consists of all formal polynomials in the variable $x$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why use an algebraic structure like $\mathbb R[x]$? Wouldn't a map $C^1(\mathbb R)\rightarrow C^0(\mathbb R)$ be more natural? Or, to loosen it, just from differentiable functions to Darboux functions? Or we could make domain and image equal as $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)\rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @MiloBrandt: Any of those, and more, can be used, depending on context.

Comment: @MiloBrandt, I just used $\mathbb{R}[x]$ because it makes explicit that the dependent variable is called $x$. To do this with $C^1(\mathbb{R}),$ I'd have to invent my own notation. Which is probably worth doing, but not in the context of a short math.stackexchange answer.

Comment: Thus you might say "derivative" is really a concept rather than a specific function (which would need a specific domain and codomain).  In computer-science parlance you might call this an example of overloading.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yep, exactly. I think an algebraist would probably characterize partial differentiation as follows: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} : \mathbb{R}[x,y,z] \leftarrow \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear, satisfies the product rule $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(pq) = p\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(q)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(p) q, $$ and satisfies $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x = 1, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}y = 0, \frac{\partial}{\partial x}z = 0.$$ So the concept of partial differentiation with respect to $x$ is really described by a list of axioms.