# Using pre-definitions to bind variables without explicitly writing them down

Tags: logic

In logic, we can use quantifiers, like $\forall$ or $\exists$, or [binders](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692562/what-do-we-call-entities-like-sum-that-bind-variables), like $\sum_x, \min_x, \prod_x$, to bind variables. At least the quantifiers [seem to also be called constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_constant), while there are other constants like numbers like 2.

But sometimes I want to write formulae that have letters (which values I do not know), that are not bound by binders or quantifiers, but are assumed to be defined or "fixed" somewhere, such that my formula becomes truth-apt.

For example, I would like to say that (for the functions $M$ and $f$)

$$
\forall x ( M(x, \theta) = f(x))
$$

is not truth-apt, because $\theta$ is not bound. But, next, I find that

$$
\exists \theta, \forall x ( M(x, \theta) = f(x))
$$

and I also find this awesome $\theta$, which I shall call $\hat\theta$. Now I want to be able to say that

$$
\forall x ( M(x, \hat\theta) = f(x)),
$$

but I am still missing the pre-definition of $\hat\theta$. Actually, $M$ and $f$ are also free variables.

However, I do not want to those down: $M$ and $f$ cannot be expressed with a mathematical expression (their values for a certain input can only be calculated via a complex computer algorithm and the details change all the time) and $\hat\theta$ is only conceptually available.

I am not even sure how to call these not-variables. Obviously they are no quantifiers or constant, but I do not want them to be variables either. I do not know the notation to make them bound.

Honestly, even if I could write $\theta$ down, I would not know how to express this.

$$
\forall x ( M(x, \theta=2) = f(x)),
$$

or

$$
\theta=2, \forall x ( M(x, \theta) = f(x)),
$$

or something else entirely?

Comment: Obviously, if you know the value of $\theta$, there is no need to write: $∀x(M(x,θ=2))$; it is enough to write $∀xM(x,2)$. Thus, in a more general context, you can write something like: "let $\theta_0$ the known value of parameter $\theta$; then $∀x(M(x,θ_0)=f(x))$..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Regarding your first sentence: Sure, but (notationaly) I want to keep the "named" variable, just bind it to 2. Regarding you second sentence: Then, I am writing prose. I was looking for a logical expression. I expected that there was a common way of binding variables in a formal way without prose.

Answer (score 0):

It should be emphasised that an open formula, a formula with unbound variable(s), is not truth-apt is a *misconception*, perhaps, due to a textbook oversimplification. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3262093/754923) and [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4452834/754923).

So far as I understand the question, the notion of [parameter](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/model-theory/#:%7E:text=A%20useful%20generalisation,with%20parameters.) can be employed (for more concrete examples of parametric definitions, see [the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory#:%7E:text=Both%20of%20the%20definitions%20mentioned%20here%20are%20parameter%2Dfree%2C%20that%20is%2C%20the%20defining%20formulas%20don%27t%20mention%20any%20fixed%20domain%20elements.%20However%2C%20one%20can%20also%20consider%20definitions%20with%20parameters%20from%20the%20model.)).